# Reactive Execution of a Dependency Graph

Tags: java, graph, reactive-programming

I need to create a service (using Java) that accepts a graph of tasks and executes them in parallel, while considering the dependencies between those tasks.

For example, let's take 6 tasks: A, B, C, D, E, F.

Dependencies are:

A -> C

B -> C, D

C -> F

D -> E

E -> F

This would create (one of the possible) parallel execution groups: A+B, C+D, E, F.

If a task execution was not successful (returned an error), its dependent tasks will not be executed.

Another requirement is to have a side effect for the task execution (or failure): notify some other service about it (which means we have to treat dependencies of a failed tasks as failed too?).

When all tasks were treated (direct success or failure + failure of a dependency), I'd like to mark this "batch" as completed (call to another service).

I thought about taking the reactive approach to this problem and use RxJava due to its async nature.

I am quite new to this approach, and while zip / switchMap combined with doOnComplete / doOnError seems like a good direction, I am not quite sure on how to use them in this context.

Would be glad to get some advice here :)

Answer (score 2):

To your query on running Observables as per the Dependency Graph (Strictly speaking Dependency-Acyclic-Graph), you can use [concat()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) and [merge()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) operators to compose observables to run as per p the give graph (DAG).

Here is how a Observable DAG, to your example, can be constructed to execute them in parallel :

```
package rxtest;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;


public class ReactiveDagTest {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReactiveDagTest.class);
    private static Executor customExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

    @Test
    public void stackOverflowTest() {
        Observable<Character> a = createObservable('A', 100);
        Observable<Character> b = createObservable('B', 150);
        Observable<Character> c = createObservable('C', 500);
        Observable<Character> d = createObservable('D', 200);
        Observable<Character> e = createObservable('E', 300);
        Observable<Character> f = createObservable('F', 400);

        logger.info("BEGIN");

        // As Observable for B is referred at two places in the graph, it needs to be cached to not to execute twice
        Observable<Character> bCached = b.cache();

        Observable.concat(
                Observable.merge(
                        Observable.concat(
                                Observable.merge(a, bCached),
                                c),
                        Observable.concat(bCached, d, e)),
                f)
                .toBlocking()
                .subscribe(i -> logger.info("Executed : " + i));

        logger.info("END");
    }

    private Observable<Character> createObservable(char c, int sleepMs) {
        Observable<Character> single = Observable.just(c)
                .flatMap(i -> Observable.<Character> create(s -> {
                    logger.info("onSubscribe Start Executing : {}", i);
                    sleep(sleepMs);
                    s.onNext(Character.valueOf(i));
                    s.onCompleted();
                }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(customExecutor)));
        return single;
    }

    private void sleep(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Output will be

```
22:19:22.107 [main] INFO rxtest.ReactiveDagTest BEGIN
22:19:22.181 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO rxtest.ReactiveDagTest onSubscribe Start Executing : A
22:19:22.181 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO rxtest.ReactiveDagTest onSubscribe Start Executing : B
22:19:22.284 [main] INFO rxtest.ReactiveDagTest Executed : A
22:19:22.333 [main] INFO rxtest.ReactiveDagTest Executed : B
22:19:22.333 [main] INFO rxtest.ReactiveDagTest Executed : B
22:19:22.333 [pool-1-thread-3] INFO rxtest.ReactiveDagTest onSubscribe Start Executing : C
22:19:22.334 [pool-1-thread-4] INFO rxtest.ReactiveDagTest onSubscribe Start Executing : D
22:19:22.534 [main] INFO rxtest.ReactiveDagTest Executed : D
22:19:22.534 [pool-1-thread-5] INFO rxtest.ReactiveDagTest onSubscribe Start Executing : E
22:19:22.833 [main] INFO rxtest.ReactiveDagTest Executed : C
22:19:22.835 [main] INFO rxtest.ReactiveDagTest Executed : E
22:19:22.835 [pool-1-thread-6] INFO rxtest.ReactiveDagTest onSubscribe Start Executing : F
22:19:23.236 [main] INFO rxtest.ReactiveDagTest Executed : F
22:19:23.236 [main] INFO rxtest.ReactiveDagTest END
```

> > If a task execution was not successful (returned an error), its dependent tasks will not be executed.

This in implicit in the above solution, if any node in the graph fails, then execution of other nodes in the graphs wont happen.